# Failed to deploy Next.js site on GitHub Pages

Tags: next.js, deployment, github-actions, github-pages, static-site

```
[Set up pages ]

  Run actions/configure-pages@v3
  with:
    static_site_generator: next
    token: ***
    enablement: false
Error: Get Pages site failed. Please verify that the repository has Pages enabled and configured to build using GitHub Actions, or consider exploring the `enablement` parameter for this action.
Error: HttpError: Not Found
```

In the pages I have my pages there. What would I do with them?

Comment: You have to show the workflow where you call the action.